# Why my Mono.onCallable ignores field with null value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller

I have this rest controller:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", value = "val")
    public Mono<Response> responseController(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest request) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> filtering.filter(
                        request.getEntity()))
                .map(MyMapper::mapToResponse);
    }
```

And in my model class I put @NotNull on entity property. Then, I wrote a test :

```
`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = MyControllerTest.TestApplication.class) {

@Test
    void invalidUrlError() {
        var request = new MyRequest();

        client.post()
                .uri("/filtering/val")
                .bodyValue(request)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isNotFound()
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("code").isEqualTo("400")
                .jsonPath("instance").exists();
    }
}`
```

But that test is failing because for some reason my response code is 200, not 400. But in Postman, I am getting 400.

I tried with adding @WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class) but without success. What is the problem with my test?

Comment: It's not really clear what is your expectations. I guess your understand that `fromCallable` returns `empty` for `null`, and then it depends on other handlers how to process an empty response. Also it's unclear what you mean by `@NotNull` annotation in this context.

Comment: Make sure that you pass the same object data to both your test and Postman (i.e your param `request`)